# How to securely deploy environment settings via config file?

Tags: django, security, deployment, fabric

I have removed API credentials and secret keys from my project's source code and repository and am now storing and applying them from a configuration file in my local environment.

What is the best way to deploy and apply the settings to my production environment? My first thought was to write a script to:

- Upload the configuration file from my local machine to the production server
- Read the configuration file and apply the settings on the production server without logging the settings or exposing them to bash history
- Delete the configuration file from the production server

Aside from potential snooping on my Internet traffic during upload, or my local machine being compromised, is there anything wrong with this approach?

This is a Django project. I am using django-environ to read / manage my settings and Fabric to upload the configuration file and remotely run commands during deployment to my server located on AWS (I'm not currently interested in using Elastic Beanstalk).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

#### how to make it secure

There are million ways of doing deployment semi-"securely" however it is extremely hard (if not impossible) to make it completely secure. The reason is very simple. Your code needs to access the sensitive information in order to run. You can obfuscate the information as much as you want but ultimately if the system gets compromised, intruder can inspect running processes hence extract all the sensitive information.

That being said, I dont see anything fundamentally wrong by using a config file to start your app as long as you follow all the standard deploy practices like using a different non-root user to run the app, etc.

#### best way to deploy

I think [12 factor](http://12factor.net/) refactored apps are considered the best practice in the industry. The 3rd rule states it pretty clearly how you should configure your applications:

> Store config in the environment

Storing config in env variables makes it super easy to deploy same application in many environments without changing any code. Doing that arguably is not 100% secure but I think if you take any normal precautions like running the server as a different user, etc you should be fine in most cases.

Obviously all this depends on the type of your application. If your application deals with super-sensitive data, then I would suggest to investigate other methods on how to deploy applications in a security-strict environments. That however is probably outside of the scope of your question and outside of my knowledge-area so maybe other smart people here at SO will be able to help.

Comment: Please re-read the question. I have already completed the step of storing configuration in environment variables. I am asking if the process I described to deploy these environment variables from my local environment to the production environment is safe, or if there is a better alternative within reason. Thank you.